# Set default value in shared Maven assembly file, but allow overrides in referencing projects

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a Maven project (we'll call it Shared Assembly Project) that defines an assembly file that looks like this:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/2.2.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/2.2.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.2.0.xsd">
    <id>shared-assembly</id>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${schema.directory}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>schemas</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

This assembly file is in `src/main/resources/assemblies/shared-assembly.xml` and can be referenced in other projects' POMs like this (which we'll call the Referencing Project):

```
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-assembly-plugin.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                        <artifactId>shared-assembly</artifactId>
                        <version>${shared.assembly.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>shared-assembly</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

The problem is the `${schema.directory}` property in `shared-assembly.xml`. I want to specify a default value in `shared-assembly.xml` or the Shared Assembly Project's pom. Then, the Referencing Project should be able to override the `schema.directory` if needed. Unfortunately, Maven doesn't allow sharing of properties from dependency pom files. It also seems like I can't just replace "${schema.directory}" with "target/generated-sources/schema", then override the `fileSet.directory` in the plugin configuration. Finally, it seems like there's no property default syntax similar to this:

`${schema.directory:target/generated-sources/schema}`

My goals:

- Shared Assembly Project specifies the default value
- If Referencing Project uses the default value, no additional configuration required
- If Referencing Project overrides the default value, it should be simple for Referencing Project to do so (no additional plugins required)

I know there are plugins that would allow the Referencing Project to pull a property from a file in the Shared Assembly Project. However, this violates goal #2, since it would need that additional plugin just to get the default value.

Comment: Looks like resonable feature ... I created issue to track it https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-1005